# How to create Azure Mgmt serializer/deserializer parameters?

Tags: python, azure-media-services, azure-sdk-python

I can see in both the latest azure-mgmt-media & storage sdk's for Python the user is expected to pass in 2 args for Serializer/Deserializer.  I've got very little Python experience and I can't figure out how to create these objects.

I can't find ANY media examples and no storage examples with the latest signature (3-01-18).  I just want to create a media service asset and I don't know why I'd need to pass these args since I'm using standard SDK types.  Can anyone point me to some examples of creating these? I can find

The documentation lists:

```
:param serializer: An object model serializer.
:param deserializer: An object model deserializer.
```

Two examples of these classes are: 
azure-sdk-for-python/azure-mgmt-media/azure/mgmt/media/operations/assets_operations.py

and

azure-sdk-for-python/azure-mgmt-storage/azure/mgmt/storage/v2018_03_01_preview/operations/blob_containers_operations.py

The signature is:
def **init**(self, client, config, serializer, deserializer):

thanks!!!

Edited to append details of my issue trying to create a media asset:

```
import azure.mgmt.media as azuremedia
client = azuremedia.AzureMediaServices(credentials,
                                            subscription_id)
assetOper = operations.AssetsOperations(client, client.config, 
               client._serialize, client._deserialize)
asset = assetOper.create_or_update(resource_group_name=resourceGroup,
                                               account_name=accountName,
                                               asset_name=assetName,
                                               parameters=None)
```

^but the create_or_update method uses the code below and MY client's _serialize doesn't have a url property so it blows up!

From the top of the create_or_update method:

```
path_format_arguments = {
        'subscriptionId': self._serialize.url("self.config.subscription_id",                 self.config.subscription_id, 'str'),
        'resourceGroupName': self._serialize.url("resource_group_name",             resource_group_name, 'str'),
        'accountName': self._serialize.url("account_name", account_name, 'str'),
        'assetName': self._serialize.url("asset_name", asset_name, 'str')
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializer and Deserializer are internal classes you're not supposed to create manually.

Instead, you must create a client that will do this for free for you. Please refer to this Storage Mgmt samples:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-python-manage

The sample does not provide examples of "blob_containers", but will give you an overview on how to use "accounts" and the same logic will apply:

```
client.blobs_containers.get(rg_name, account_name, container_name)
```

You probably should do the short tutorial on SDK too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-get-started?view=azure-python

There is no samples yet for media, but same logic applies.

(I own this code at MS)

Comment: I got a little further, but apparently don't have the correct permissions on my AAD stub.  I know how to add permissions (did this to get the storage api working), but I can't find any builtin roles that mention media services.   I added API contributer but that didn't help.  Any ideas?    Error is:  The client 'xxx' with object id 'yyy' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/assets/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{subId]/resourceGroups/{resGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/{mediaSvcAccountName}/assets/{assetName}'.

Comment: That would be a ARM question and not a Python one at this level.  That being said, you can 1) create your own role 2) try as Owner or Contributor as a quick test. If it's still doesn't work, open an issue on Azure mentionning the ARM question.

Comment: Thanks. It works as owner, but I don't like having to give that much privilege.  The code is almost working.  I use AssetOperation.create_or_update to create the media asset and then switch over to the storage api and put the files into the associated storage container.  However, the uploaded files don't show up through the media asset even though I can see them in the asset's storage container.  Is there an additional call to "join" them?   It would be really nice to have an example.  The docs aren't very helpful if you don't know the "flow" of the actions required.

Comment: Hello @LaurentMazuel. Thanks for the info above. You mention how we are to use a client which will create the serializer and deserializer.  I'm very familiar with creating the client in the SDK, but I don't understand how the client creates these arguments.  Is it a matter of passing in client._serializer and client._deserializer? (per source code var names: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-databricks/0.1.0/_modules/azure/mgmt/databricks/databricks_client.html).  I'm trying to use the databricks module of the azure python sdk to provision a databricks service.